# Django Template + JavaScript: How concatenate Django template url with JavaScript variable.

Tags: javascript, python, django

### Problem

I want to concatinate JavaScript variable with Django Template URL.

### How

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var city_url = "{% url 'explore_city' javascriptVariable templateVariable %}";
}
```

Howto?

Suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, because the django template is rendered before it ever gets to the user's browser. As an alternative, you could generate the url without using `{%url ... %}`. For example, you could have something like.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var templateVariable = "{{templateVariable}}";
    var city_url = "/explore-city/" + javascriptVariable + "/" + templateVariable;
}
```

Comment: Can we use with oprator with JavaScript?